# React custom http-hook abortController() bug

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks

I have this custom http hook with abort when you try to go to a different page (I saw it in a tutorial but I am not truly sure I need it). When I fetch data with it and useEffect(), I have this error on the backend but the request is executed and everything is as planned. My question is, how to improve my code so it does not throw this error and do I need this functionality with abortController() ?

http-hook.ts

```
import { useCallback, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { selectError, showError } from "src/redux/error";
import { selectLoading, startLoading, stopLoading } from "src/redux/loading";

export const useHttpClient = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const error = useSelector(selectError);
  const loading = useSelector(selectLoading);

  const activeHttpRequests: any = useRef([]);

  const sendRequest = useCallback(
    async (url, method = "GET", body = null, headers = {}) => {
      dispatch(startLoading());
      const httpAbortCtrl = new AbortController();
      activeHttpRequests.current.push(httpAbortCtrl);

      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method,
          body,
          headers,
          signal: httpAbortCtrl.signal,
        });

        const responseData = await response.json();

        activeHttpRequests.current = activeHttpRequests.current.filter(
          (reqCtrl) => reqCtrl !== httpAbortCtrl
        );

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(responseData.message);
        }

        dispatch(stopLoading());
        return responseData;
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch(showError(err.message));
        dispatch(stopLoading());
        throw err;
      }
    },
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      activeHttpRequests.current.forEach((abortCtrl: any) => abortCtrl.abort());
    };
  }, []);

  return { loading, error, sendRequest };
};
```

UserInfo.tsx

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHttpClient } from "src/hooks/http-hook";
import classes from "./UserInfo.module.css";

const UserInfo = () => {
  const { sendRequest } = useHttpClient();
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<any>();

  const userId = useParams<any>().userId;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCurrentUser = async () => {
      try {
        const responseData = await sendRequest(
          `http://localhost:5000/api/user/${userId}`
        );
        setCurrentUser(responseData.user);
        console.log("currentUser ", currentUser);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        
      }
    };
    fetchCurrentUser();
  }, [sendRequest ,userId]);

  return currentUser ? (
    <Fragment>
      <div className={classes.cover} />
      <div className={classes.user_info}>
        <img
          alt="user_img"
          src={`http://localhost:5000/${currentUser.image}`}
          className={classes.user_img}
        />
        <div className={classes.text}>
          <p>
            Name: {currentUser.name} {currentUser.surname}
          </p>
          <p>Email: {currentUser.email}</p>
          <p>Age: {currentUser.age}</p>
        </div>
      </div>{" "}
    </Fragment>
  ) : (
    <p>No current user</p>
  );
};

export default UserInfo;
```

Backend

getCurrentUser.ts controller

```
const getCurrentUser = async (
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response,
  next: express.NextFunction
) => {
  const userId = req.params.userId;

  let user;
  try {
    user = await User.findById(userId);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError("Could not fetch user", 500);
    return next(error);
  }
  res.json({ user: user.toObject({ getters: true }) });
};
```

Comment: so what error says? how does route look like at Express? So far, to me it seems rather as an issue with specifying URL on client side(nothing to do with a hook) or route on backend side(nothing to do with a hook again)

Comment: I do not believe its an URL or route problem (you can see them both uploaded) as the request is valid and executed. The error is: DOMException: The user aborted a request.

Comment: so `useEffect` aborts request? what debugging shows? probably component is unmounted when you don't expect, say due to parent remountes